# replace mysql value .58 with 0.58

Tags: mysql

`carat` field contains values like .58(0.58). I need to get all records between .58 and 1.90. How can i fill values with `0` if it not present and make selection between 0.58 and 1.90?

Comment: What is the character type? Numeric or String?

Comment: string of course, need to convert to float also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET carat = carat + 0.0;
```

you can select

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (carat + 0.0) >= 0.58
AND (carat + 0.0) >= 1.90;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (carat + 0.0) BETWEEN 0.58 AND 1.90;
```

Naturally, this would be a full table scan

Did you have other columns that you check for in your queries ???

Answer (score 0):

> *need to convert to float also*

Use `cast` on `carat` field.

```
select 
    cast( carat as decimal ) carat
from
    my_table
where 
    cast( carat as decimal ) between 0.58 and 1.90
;
```